# String index out of range in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-extraction

So I am writing code to read a file and print out the content as (fileID, sentenceID, wordID, word). It keeps telling me `for word in line[0].split('ZZ'): IndexError: string index out of range`. So how do I fix this? Thanks.

```
lineCount = 0
wordCount = 0
for line in file[0].split('ZZ'):
    lineCount +=1
    for word in line[0].split('ZZ'):
        wordCount +=1
        print fileNumber + '|' + str(lineCount) + '|' + str(wordCount) + word +'\n'
```

Comment: Please indent your code using only four spaces. Don't indent using tabs. Don't mix spaces and tabs.

Comment: Aren't those `for` loops supposed to be nested? Also, what is the content of `line` just before the second (inner?) loop?

Comment: I've edited your code by replacing tabs with four spaces. Now: what is `line[0]`. What is `file[0]`? What is `file`? Show us a sample of your input.

Comment: I am new to Python and not really aware of the tag / space difference. Just tried to indent all by tagging. The problem is still there. Didn't post the whole code, which is a bit long. So I have multiple files,`file[0]` tells python to start from the first one, and the same for `line[0]`. I want it to count from the first file, file line and first word, and then add the numbers up.

Comment: You misunderstood our question, we'd like to know what file and line are in terms of python types. Is file a list of strings that were already read from files?

Comment: Most likely you have a "blank line" somewhere (i.e. sometihng like `aaaZZ` or `aaaZZZZ`. In such case `line` would be empty, so `0` would be outside of string bounds.

Comment: Sorry. 'File[0]' is a list of strings, 'line[0]' is a string. Your question kind of gives me some hint, will try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `for word in line.split('ZZ'):` instead of `for word in line[0].split('ZZ'):`.

This `file[0].split('ZZ'):` returns list of strings, so `line` is one of those strings. 
`line.split('ZZ')` will return list of strings once again, but now `word` will be one of those strings.

**EDIT**
Here is example for your question in comment:

```
line = "one-two threeZZfour five-six seven eight nineZZten"
for word in line.split('ZZ')
    print word

output>>
one-two three
four five-six seven eight nine
ten

for word in line.split('-')
    print word
output>>
one
two threeZZfour five
six seven eight nineZZten

for word in line.split()# or split(' ')
    print word
output>>
one-two
threeZZfour
five-six
seven
eight
nineZZten
```

Comment: This does help the code run, but my output is (fileID, sentenceID, wordID, sentence) instead of (fileID, sentenceID, wordID, word).

Comment: you are using 'ZZ' as delimiter for sentence : line.split('ZZ'). You should use line.split() if you want to get every word of sentence (delimiter is space in that case)

Comment: Oh, this works!!! So what is the difference bwtween `'ZZ'` and `' '`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to pass delimiter to split method, it can be any character or word .I've edited my answer and added example

Comment: since you do not have 'ZZ' in your 'line' split('ZZ') doesn't match any 'ZZ' so it dosn't split line. It returns the whole line (sentence)

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's see what we get, step by step:

```
for line in file[0].split('ZZ'):
```

If this line is correct, then file must be a list of strings (because of the `split` method). What is the `line` then? Well, `split` returns a list of strings. Thus line is a string.

```
for word in line[0].split('ZZ'):
```

Sine `line` is a string, `line[0]` is a single char (or empty string). This is where things begin not to make sense. The error you get is caused by trying to index an empty string, i.e.

```
>>>''[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

However, that's not all. Applying `split('ZZ')` to a single char will return, well, a list with one element - that char (or an empty string). Now the `for word` part doesn't make sense, since you're iterating over a list with one element that's a single char. I don't this this is what you want...

Since file is apparently a list of strings, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
for line in file[0].split('ZZ'):
    lineCount+=1
    for word in line.split('ZZ'):
```

Comment: I did try this code inspired by you and another reply. This time it did print the info out. I have fileID, sentenceID, and wordID, but the words are not printed out correctly. It looks like this: `a9500006|2|2 9500006 Wang This award for a Grant Opportunity for Academic Liaiso
n with

a9500006|3|3 Industry (GOALI) research project will develop a new methodology fo
r reducing

a9500006|4|4 geometric variation in aluminum automotive space frames. The space
frame`